# Add a List into a 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

How is it possible to add a List into an 2D ArrayList in java. I've got some Lists, and I want to add them into a 2D ArrayList. I found that is not possible to initialize with new a List. So I am trying to add a list into Arraylist.

```
   ArrayList<List<Feature>> featureMatrix= new   ArrayList<ArrayList<Feature>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.size(); i++) {
        List<Feature> temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < imageNames.get(i).size(); j++) {

            System.out.println(train_path + fileNames.get(i) + "/" + imageNames.get(i).get(j));
            File img = new File(train_path + fileNames.get(i) + "/" + imageNames.get(i).get(j));
            BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(img);

            Extractor e = new Extractor();
            temp = e.computeSiftFeatures(in);
            System.out.println(temp);   
            featureMatrix.add(temp);
        }

    }
```

The above code returns a type mismatch.

Comment: Where is the other list declared?

Comment: I ve got temp which is List<Feature> type and I wanto to add all these temp Lists into a 2s List.

Comment: what does `e.computeSiftFeatures(in)` return? `List<Feature>`?

Comment: yes e.computeSiftFeatures(in) returns List<Feature>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but an `ArrayList<List<Feature>>` is *not* an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Feature>>`, that's why you get the type mismatch (read about generics covariance in Java). That being said, your nested list should be defined as:

```
List<List<Feature>> featureMatrix = new ArrayList<List<Feature>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring `featureMatrix` as:

```
List<List<Feature>> featureMatrix= new ArrayList<List<Feature>>();
```

This way you are using a generic interface as the declared type and assigning it a concrete implementation.
You can still write:

```
featureMatrix.add(new ArrayList<Feature>());
```

because an `ArrayList` **is** a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable using generics, the generic type must match.

```
ArrayList<List<Feature>> featureMatrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Feature>>();
```

Here you are trying to assign an `ArrayList *of ArrayList*` to a variable that only accepts an `ArrayList *of List*`, hence the compile error.

Inheritance doesn't work automatically here, unless you use the `extends` or `super` keyword in the generics declaration.

Change your `featureMatrix` instantiation to:

```
List<List<Feature>> featureMatrix = new ArrayList<List<Feature>>();
```

Using interfaces where possible instead of implementations will make your code more flexible. Assigning an `ArrayList of List` to a `List of List` works because an `ArrayList` is a `List`.

More about generics here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/